# How to center a group of images in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, center

I'm making a simple website for a friend and I can't seem to center 5 png images?
I have them in a div and the images itself are using display: block; and margin: auto; to center which did work earlier using for only 1 picture as you'll see down below.
My code:

```css
 .middleContent{
        width: 100%;
        top: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    h2{
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
    }
    
    .middlePhoto1, .middlePhoto2, .middlePhoto3, .middlePhoto4, .middlePhoto5{
        width: 15%;
        padding-right: 2%;
        padding-left: 2%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
        <img class="topContent" src="img/homepage.jpg"></img>
        <div class="middleContent">
         <img class="middlePhoto1" src="img/icon1.png"></img>     
         <img class="middlePhoto2" src="img/icon2.png"></img>  
         <img class="middlePhoto3" src="img/icon3.png"></img>    
         <img class="middlePhoto4" src="img/icon4.png"></img>
         <img class="middlePhoto5" src="img/icon5.png"></img>
        </div>
       </div>
```

So I edited it a bit and now the images are in the center of the screen but still not centered in the center screen if that made sense. I'm using only 5% padding right and i have like 300px left but still the fifth icon won't fit when it does have plenty of pixel space left???!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: For the images give them the same class as your treating the classes as id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
.middleContent{
    /* Use text align to center them; */
    text-align: center;
}

.middleContent1, 
.middleContent2, 
.middleContent3, 
.middleContent4, 
.middleContent5{
    /* Display them as inline-blocks; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or even better, instead of giving them *all* a different class, use CSS selectors to do the job:

```
.middleContent > img {
    /* Display them as inline-blocks; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The main problem is your `float: left;`. `Float`s invalidate the `margin: auto`, as the intention of `float` is to allow other items to wrap around it. You could try taking that off, as I don't see a need for it here in the first place.

#### Update

You were asking how to float two blocks centered next to each other without a gap in between, well, you could do that using font-size and inline-blocks. Try the following:

```
html {
    /* Make sure you have a fontsize here as it will be useful for modern browser resetting (this is the `rem` value, or Root EM) */
    font-size: 16px;
}

.middleContent {
    /* Eliminate any gaps between inline-block elements by setting the font-size to 0 */
    font-size: 0;
    /* Set a percentage width to make your blocks scalable */
    width: 50%;
    /* Set a max-width to make sure your images stop scaling at some point */
    max-width: 200px;
}
.middleContent * {
    /* Make sure any tags inside your block WILL be able to contain text */
    /* Start by defining it in pixels for older browsers */
    font-size: 16px;
    /* Then reset your font-size to the rem value. Older browser will fall back to 16px, but its not a huge issue. */
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Your code did it! yes! I though float: left could be used when you have 2 objects and both are 50% in 100% div that the second one will fit next to eachother. That's what I tried with the 5 images.

Comment: @mustafatosuncu Yeah that works but only if you `float` the `outer box`, which invalidates your `margin: auto`. You could use `inline-block` and reset the `font-size` to `0`. (so: `html { font-size: 16px; /* This is to use rems - usefull for resetting ems further down the line.*/} .outer-block: { font-size: 0; /* This eliminates any gaps between inline-block elements. */ } .outer-block * { font-size: 16px; font-size: 1rem; /* This resets all child elements' font-size again */}` would remove all margins of elements placed inside your outer block.) Actually let me change my post for that.

Comment: It doesn't work after I added a h2 header to each of them..  I'll update my codes

Comment: @mustafatosuncu Thats because your `h2` is _not an inline element_. You need to define that again. The best way to ensure this is to add the following line: `.middleContent > * { display: inline-block; }` which will apply inline block to all _direct_ children of `.middleContent`. You have to start thinking in blocks if you want to do this. If each `img` gets an `h2`, you'll need to wrap both together in a `div`('block') and apply block styles to the `div` (aka `div` needs the `img` style and `img` probs needs a `width: 100%;` to make sure it doesn't overflow).

Comment: But h2 is seperated from the img. The img is wrapped in middlecontent and h2 is in maincontent. The simple problem is that I can't center img next to each other now.. When I leave out the h2 and go back to it's previous state, the images keeps like this where 4 are floated left next to otherother and the fifth image get's centered under the other images. Is this one of these cases where these codes will work on your device but won't work on mine(lenovo laptop)?

Comment: @mustafaTosuncu Its not related to device, your image is now _an inline element_ which means its inline with the text. So if you want it on separate lines, you have to put in on separate lines using line breaks `<br />`. You also need to give your outer block a width if you want it to push away from the other surrounding blocks. Try to play with the idea of `inline` as its easy to grasp and you'll be sorted once you do (for this particular case). (_Kortom: inline is gebaseerd op tekst, dus probeer de blokken te zien als woorden in tekst_)

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply. I removed the h2 for now and now the images are perfectly centered next to eachother. Using </br> didn't work out.. How would you continue from here? I updated my html and css

Comment: If the result is what you wanted, then try to see why the h2 messed it up. Use the `inspect element` to see how your h2 is layed out, then try to make it push other elements. It ight be as simple as giving you h2 a `width 100%`. You could also separate your code into blocks and then align the blocks, there are many options. Have a play around and check out allk the CSS available to you. Good luck!

Comment: Hey! I played a little bit with it but h2 sucks and I'm never using it again! I had this sudden lightbulb above my head. I said: "Why don't i doodily doo use table boo yeaahhh" and that's what I did and it's so much easier and you feel like you are more in control. CSS rules are sometimes so annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `margin: auto` to the image container `middleContent` and then change the width of the images. It is good practice to only change styles in the CSS, so removing the width from the images and adding a new CSS rule for them will give you greater control. I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c16vnxy/) so you can see what I propose in action. As mentioned above you don't need all the different classes, you can use a CSS selector like `.middleContent img`.

```
.middleContent {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

.middleContent img {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, yes the `middleContent` would be centered, but the images would be on the left-hand side of the `middleContent` block...

Comment: His code did work and also the way it should be. It is centered  in the div itself. But others didn't quite understood my question. I wanted them next to each other centered. But thank you all guys, you are all awesome. But wait.. it didn't work, it's centered because of the width but as soon as I change them, you can see it's not centered..

Answer (score 1):

you can try with align as middle find the below code snippet

```
.middleContent1, 
.middleContent2,
.middleContent3,
.middleContent4,
.middleContent5,
 {
 align:middle;
  }
```

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/pwwacgg1/2/